# how to solve Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to use [Grid.MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC) in my code. The example seems simple enough but when I try to use it I keep getting an `ArrayTypeMismatchException`.

This is my code. Any ideas on how i can solve it?

```
//This is the my cshtml code.

 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name");
        columns.Add(c => c.Operation).Titled("Operation").Filterable(true);
    }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)



//This is my controller code.

public ActionResult ListAllAuthorization()
{
    IList<AuthorizationWrapper> authorizations;
    using (GenericRepositoryV2 repo = new GenericRepositoryV2())
    {
        authorizations = repo.GetAllAuthorization();

    }
    return View(authorizations);
}
```

If it makes a difference, my configuration:

- MVC 5
- .Net framework 4.5

**Update 1:** The stack trace:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.SetItem(Int32 index, T item)
at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.SetItem(Int32 index, RouteBase item)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.get_RequestContext()
at GridMvc.Html.GridHtmlOptions`1.RenderPartialViewToString(String viewName, Object model, ViewContext viewContext)
at GridMvc.Html.GridHtmlOptions`1.ToHtmlString()
at System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object value)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, Object content)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(Object value)
at ASP._Page_Views_Admin_ListAllAuthorization_cshtml.Execute() in e:\Oman-Erp\OmanERP\Views\Admin\ListAllAuthorization.cshtml:line 28
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace. We've no idea which part is actually failing.

Comment: @Manpreet Singh, what does the `repo.GetAllAuthorization()` do? Can you post the code and full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @RePierre `GetAllAuthorization()` returns an `IList<AuthorizationWrapper>`

Comment: @JonSkeet Added the stack trace. Couldn't glean anything actionable from it myself.

Comment: Well aside from anything else, it appears to be in the `ControllerContext.RequestContext` getter, which I wouldn't expect to have anything to do with the code you've shown. Definitely worth having - although I don't know enough to fix it myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot but I think you should try it.

According to the [documentation page of `ArrayTypeMismatchException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ArrayTypeMismatchException is thrown when the system cannot convert the element to the type declared for the array. For example, an element of type String cannot be stored in an Int32 array because conversion between these types is not supported.

Looking at the stack trace you provided, I'm inclined to believe that there is a problem with the model you are passing to the view/grid. As can bee seen from the action method, you're passing a list of `AuthorizationWrapper` objects and the type checking would prevent you from storing something else in that list so the problem is somewhere in between.

Start by checking the `Model` property of the view in debug; if everything is ok, just download the [source code](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), build it locally and see (in debug mode) where the exception pops up. That's the great part of Open Source :)

Comment: In my case I had effectively done `BaseType[] items = new[] { new ActualType() };` so while I thought I was dealing with an array of `BaseType`, the implementation was actually of `ActualType`.

The solution of course was to explicitly type the array on creation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include this in web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```